# how to treat factors as strings and filter data frames with them

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't find a way to easily filter a `data.frame` on factors, that I thought I could use `str_detect` to treat as strings. I want to filter on `df$kind` not including `flow-delivery`, `storage`, or `flow-channel`.  I could maybe add a column with `mutate(kind2 = as.character(kind)` and filter on that, but I'd rather not have the redundancy, and I'm sure I'm missing the obvious.

```
 library(dplyr)
 plot_monoth_ts <- function(df, yearmon, rawval, rawunit, dv, study, yrmin, yrmax) 
 {df %>% filter(str_detect(!kind, 'flow-delivery|storage|flow-channel')) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = yearmon, y = rawval, color = study, linetype = dv))+geom_line()}
```

which returns this error:

```
  Warning message:
  In Ops.factor(kind) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

thank you,
Dave

Comment: The column is `factor`.  Convert it to `character` i.e. `filter(str_detect(!as.character(kind), '..`  It is not clear without a reproducible example, but i think the `!` doesn't make sense inside the `str_detect`

Comment: You can just convert temporarily, without creating a new column, e.g. `str_detect(as.character(kind), 'flow-delivery|storage|flow-channel')`. I think the `!` should also sit *outside* of the `str_detect()` call.

Comment: thank you @akrun and @Marius. `df  %>% filter(!str_detect(as.character(kind), 'flow_delivery|storage|flow_channel'))`worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-thinking it! :> No character conversion is necessary. As long as the factor has a `label` associated with each of its `level`s, you can refer to the levels as if they were strings.

```
iris %>% head

# Note that 'Species' is a Factor with 3 levels.

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
# 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
# 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica
# 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
# 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica

omitted <- c("versicolor", "setosa")
filter(iris, !(Species %in% omitted)) %>% sample_n(5)

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 22          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0 virginica
# 34          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5 virginica
# 41          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4 virginica
# 17          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8 virginica
# 19          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
```

Note the `!(x %in% y)` construct.

---

Quick comparison of speed:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(filter(iris, !(Species %in% c("versicolor", "setosa"))))

# Unit: microseconds
# min     lq       mean     median   uq       max
# 568.189 575.8505 600.3869 580.8085 603.3435 870.7620

microbenchmark(filter(iris, !str_detect(as.character(Species), "versicolor|setosa")))

# Unit: microseconds
# min     lq       mean     median   uq      max
# 620.169 633.6910 671.0874 656.8275 687.325 928.1510
```

As expected, converting to character and then using regex pattern-matching is slower, even on a small dataset like `iris`.

Comment: thank you @DuckPyjamas. In this case I prefer not to need establishing another vector but that's good information nonetheless.

Comment: You don't need to make a new vector, it was only for clarity. 
`filter(iris, !(Species %in% c("versicolor", "setosa")))` 
works just fine, of course.

Comment: ahh, thanks! :) curious, a decent bet that for an average large data frame they're equally efficient, `str_detect` vs `%in%`?

Comment: Your way is slower because of character conversion and the use of regex pattern matching. I updated my answer with `microbenchmark` times. Of course, the difference between 870 microseconds and 928 microseconds is not really a problem for average-sized datasets. The real question to ask is whether you or someone else will get confused about your solution 6 months from now.